# Click event enabled in OnEachFeature triggering spontaneously

Tags: leaflet

When I load the map, a click event fires for every one of the two thousand features even though I have not clicked the mouse. I don't know why this happens or how to get it to wait for a real click. Here is my js code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

            var map = L.map('map').setView([37.8, -96], 4);

            L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
                maxZoom: 18,
                attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                    '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                    'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
                id: 'mapbox/light-v9',
                tileSize: 512,
                zoomOffset: -1
            }).addTo(map);


            // control that shows state info on hover
            var info = L.control();

            info.onAdd = function (map) {
                this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
                this.update();
                return this._div;
            };

            info.update = function (props) {
                this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>COVID-19 by County</h4>' +  (props ?
                    '<b>' + props.name + '</b><br />' + props.deaths + ' deaths per 100,000 people in past 30 days<sup>2</sup>'
                    : 'Hover over a county');
            };

            info.addTo(map);


            // get color depending on population density value
            function getColor(d) {
                return d > 100 ? '#800026' :
                        d > 80  ? '#BD0026' :
                        d > 20  ? '#E31A1C' :
                        d > 10  ? '#FC4E2A' :
                        d > 5   ? '#FD8D3C' :
                        d > 2   ? '#FEB24C' :
                        d > 1   ? '#FED976' :
                                    '#FFEDA0';
            }

            function style(feature) {
                return {
                    weight: 2,
                    opacity: 1,
                    color: 'white',
                    dashArray: '3',
                    fillOpacity: 0.7,
                    fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.deaths)
                };
            }

            function highlightFeature(e) {
                var layer = e.target;

                layer.setStyle({
                    weight: 5,
                    color: '#666',
                    dashArray: '',
                    fillOpacity: 0.7
                });

                if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
                    layer.bringToFront();
                }

                info.update(layer.feature.properties);
            }

            var geojson;

            function resetHighlight(e) {
                geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
                info.update();
            }

            function zoomToFeature(e) {
                map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
            }

            function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
                layer.on({
                    mouseover: highlightFeature,
                    mouseout: resetHighlight,
                    click: get_data()
                    // click: zoomToFeature
                });
            }

            geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
                style: style,
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature
            }).addTo(map);

            map.attributionControl.addAttribution('Population data &copy; <a href="http://census.gov/">US Census Bureau</a>');


            var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

            legend.onAdd = function (map) {

                var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
                    grades = [0, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000],
                    labels = [],
                    from, to;

                for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
                    from = grades[i];
                    to = grades[i + 1];

                    labels.push(
                        '<i style="background:' + getColor(from + 1) + '"></i> ' +
                        from + (to ? '&ndash;' + to : '+'));
                }

                div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
                return div;
            };

            legend.addTo(map);

        </script>
```

Comment: This is not enough of code to guess why this is happening. Please edit your question and add all relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing...

```
        function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
            layer.on({
                mouseover: highlightFeature,
                mouseout: resetHighlight,
                click: get_data()
                // click: zoomToFeature
            });
        }
```

So for the `click` event, your're **not** attaching the `get_data` function as an event handler, but the **return value** of the `get_data` function as the event handler.